# Javax validation are not carried to Immutable generated class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pom.xml, immutables-library

I'm using immutables.org library and want to add Javax annotation validation. But I noticed that the validations are not being carried to the generated class. I thought that immutables.org were compatible with validations annotations.
I have *spring-boot-starter-validation* and *javax.validation* dependencies.

immutable

```
@Value.Immutable
public interface Entity {
    @Valid @Size(min = 19)
    int age();

    @Valid @NotBlank
    String name();
}
```

Controller:

```
    @PostMapping("/entity/")
    public ResponseEntity post2(@RequestBody @Valid ImmutableEntity entity) {


        return  new ResponseEntity<Object>("", HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testImmutable</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>testImmutable</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.immutables</groupId>
            <artifactId>value</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Rempve the `javax.validation` dependency, those are already part of `spring-boot-starter-validation`. ALso the `@Valid` shouldn't be needed on that field, how are you using this interface for validation?

Comment: I am using it as a controller method parameter : "@RequestBody @Valid ImmutableEntity entity"

Comment: @M.Deinum Edited the original question with the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Really, `@Valid` should not be set in a model for field or class, only for controller method's argument.
2. `@Size` is not available for `int` field, you need to use `@Range` or `@Min`.
3. In your interface you annotated the abstract methods, not fields. How does validator relate a validating fields `age` and `name` with methods `age()` and `name()`? When they will be called (their implementations) than a validator will try to validate them. But not a model's fields.